# Can't set variable in string

Tags: php, json, string, variables

So I'm trying to send a dynamic email with PHP. Now here's what I have

```
    $postString = '{
            "key": "xxx",
            "message": {
                    "html": "this is the emails html content",
                    "text": "this is the emails text content",
                    "subject": "this is the subject",
                    "from_email": "email@email.com",
                    "from_name": "Joe",
                    "to": [
                    {
                            "email": "Joe@ Joe",
                            "name": "Joe@ Joe"
                    }
                    ],

                    "attachments": [

                    ]
            },
            "async": false
    }';
```

Now I want `"html"` to be a variable. So I did this

```
"html": $var,
```

Sadly that doesn't work. Not does `{}` or using single quotes. Any ideas? It gets picked up as a string, by the way.

Comment: **Never** roll your own JSON. Use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/function.json-encode.php)

Answer (score 2):

[Variables are not interpolated in strings delimited by single quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single). There are a few ways around this. The following example uses [concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

```
$postString = '{
        "key": "xxx",
        "html": "' . $var . '",
        "message": {
                "html": "this is the emails html content",
                "text": "this is the emails text content",
                "subject": "this is the subject",
                "from_email": "email@email.com",
                "from_name": "Joe",
                "to": [
                {
                        "email": "Joe@ Joe",
                        "name": "Joe@ Joe"
                }
                ],

                "attachments": [

                ]
        },
        "async": false
}';
```

To be honest with you, this would be a lot easier if you just used an array and then encoded it into JSON using [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comment, this would work a lot better

```
$post = [
    'key' => 'xxx',
    'message' => [
        'html' => $var,
        'text' => 'this is the emails text content',
        'subject' => 'this is the subject',
        'from_email' => 'email@email.com',
        'to' => [
            ['email' => 'Joe@ Joe', 'name' => 'Joe@ Joe']
        ],
        'attachments' => []
    ],
    'async' => false
];

$postString = json_encode($post);
```

---

Obligatory legacy PHP note: If you're stuck on a PHP version lower than 5.4, you obviously can't use the shorthand array notation. Substitute `[]` with `array()` if that's the case.